# Adding -javaagent to Tomcat 6 server, where do I put it and in what format?

Tags: java, tomcat, javaagents, catalina

I´m trying to install an application  health monitoring application that can monitor J2EE web transactions and I need to put a javaagent into my Tomcat somehow but am not clear on exactly how to do this, I am using Linux and have been instructed by the software company that makes this product to do something like below:

```
-javaagent:<Path to the WebTransactionAgent.jar>
```

I have received further support from them and they basically said to put this into the appropriate .sh file (but they weren´t able to tell me which file that is for Tomcat)

I tried putting this in the catalina.sh file but it does not seem to be working:

```
JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -javaagent:"C:\WebTransactionAgent.jar"
```

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Unix/Linux, do this in `<tomcat_home>/bin/setenv.sh`, e.g.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/path/to/YourJar.jar"
```

You might need to create this file if not present and `chmod` it to `711` or `755`.

For Windows, the counterpart is `setenv.bat`.

Comment: thanks, just a note, however you mis-spelled javaagent above so if anyone is copying and pasting this may throw them off

Comment: i need to add aspectj Loadviewer jar in tomcat7  catalina.bat file i place at the first line but it wont work. set JAVA_OPTS= -javaagent:D:\log4jproject\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar and i tried with this also set CATALINA_OPTS= -javaagent:D:\log4jproject\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

Comment: Alternatively, You might also find CATALINA_OPTS in your <tomcat_home>/bin/startup.sh

Answer (score 3):

To add to [mindas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697104/6340)' answer, the `-javaagent` command could also be added to the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable in one of the following (if they exist):

`<tomcat_home>/conf/tomcat6.conf`

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -javaagent:/full/path/to/YourJar.jar"
```

or `<tomcat_home>/bin/catalina.sh`

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:/full/path/to/YourJar.jar"
```

Comment: i need to add aspectj Loadviewer jar in tomcat7  catalina.bat file i place at the first line but it wont work. set JAVA_OPTS= -javaagent:D:\log4jproject\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar and i tried with this also set CATALINA_OPTS= -javaagent:D:\log4jproject\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar

Answer (score 0):

Use JAVA_OPTS as CATALINA_OPTS would not allow JVM options `[option2]=[value2]`.

Example, for adding jacocoagent.jar with options as below, only JAVA_OPTS will work.

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -javaagent:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/tmp/jacoco.exec"
```

Comment: i need to add aspectj Loadviewer jar in tomcat7  catalina.bat file i place at the first line but it wont work. set JAVA_OPTS= -javaagent:D:\log4jproject\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar and i tried with this also set CATALINA_OPTS= -javaagent:D:\log4jproject\aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar