# Docs for installing Lucee?

Tags: lucee

I wish to use an alternative to ColdFusion. Researching Railo, I found the pointers to Lucee. There do not appear to be any docs explaining how to set up a Linux/Apache/Tomcat/MySQL platform for Lucee, and then install Lucee on top of it. I've tried setting up such a platform for Railo, but got stuck trying to get Railo talking to Apache over both http and https.

I wish to avoid the "all in one" installers that include Tomcat, as I'd like to use yum to keep Tomcat up to date on security patches.

If I've just overlooked the Lucee docs, can someone please point me to them? And if they don't exist, how could one "translate" the Railo docs to work with Lucee, and get the Apache-Lucee connection working?

UPDATE 2016-04-06: Thanks to all who answered. It looks like you've helped a number of people! I never was able to get Lucee running, but this was for lack of time, not lack of instructions. The powers that be also decided to move to an outsourced web design and hosting solution, and the firm that won the bid uses Drupal.

Comment: Whilst this page is Windows specific pretty much the same applies to Linux: https://bitbucket.org/lucee/lucee/wiki/How%20to%20set%20up%20a%20Lucee%20Server%20on%20Windows

Comment: @andrewdixon -- It looks like what I need. Working through it presently. Thank you!

Comment: The last step in the Windows install instructions don't seem to translate to Linux. What if anything needs to be done on Linux?

Comment: @DwightTuinstra if you are referring to the javaagent option, you can add that into setenv.sh as detailed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697063/adding-javaagent-to-tomcat-6-server-where-do-i-put-it-and-in-what-format however I can't actually find where I did that on my jar-installed servers

Comment: FWIW, there is always cfmldeveloper.com if you want a remote development/staging environment

Comment: Lucee running on Vagrant is super easy to setup and is available here: https://github.com/writecodedrinkcoffee/vagrant-lemtl

Answer (score 4):

For Linux installs (Ubuntu) Digital Ocean has a great tutorial on installing Railo.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-railo-cfml-engine-with-tomcat-and-apache-on-a-debian-7-or-ubuntu-13-vps

You can follow these same instructions to install Lucee just...

**replace**

> wget www.getrailo.org/down.cfm?item=/railo/remote/download/4.1.1.009/tomcat/linux/railo-4.1.1.009-pl0-linux-x64-installer.run -O railo.run

**with:**

> wget http://lucee.viviotech.net/downloader.cfm/id/136/file/lucee-4.5.1.022-pl0-linux-x64-installer.run -O railo.run

And everything else is the same.

note - If you want to get the latest installer just go to http://lucee.org/downloads.html scroll down to the Installers section and right-click the Linux 64-Bit link and copy the link url.  Then replace the link in the wget above with the one you just copied.

Comment: is it -O railo.run? it should be Lucee.run, otherwise Railo guys will sue ;)

Comment: the -O railo.run is just what you are saving the filename on your server as.   you can literally name it -O free_cf.run and no one will know.  But to keep it consistent, yes, you should probably rename that to -O lucee.run.   Just remember what you rename it to, because the next step in the install process requires you to actually run that file.

Answer (score 2):

Installation of Lucee on your local machine, following this help link : [How to Set Up Railo CFML Engine with Tomcat and Apache on a Debian 7 or Ubuntu 13 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-railo-cfml-engine-with-tomcat-and-apache-on-a-debian-7-or-ubuntu-13-vps)

Open your terminal and follow the instruction given below

*Commands :*

1. `aptitude update`
2. `aptitude -y upgrade`

*Installing Apache*

3. `aptitude -y install apache2`

*Install Lucee*

4. `wget http://cdn.lucee.org/downloader.cfm/id/143/file/lucee-4.5.2.018-pl0-linux-x64-installer.run -O lucee.run`
5. `chmod 744 lucee.run`
6. `run sudo ./lucee.run`

Follow the instructions.

That's it ..

Comment: Hi @Ritesh. I have followed all steps based on your shared link and I do not have any problem during the installation except the "Final Steps". In my terminal I type [ nano /opt/lucee/tomcat/conf/server.xml ] and I got this [ Error reading /opt/lucee/tomcat/conf/server.xml: Permission denied ]

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps above, and everything worked until I got to run sudo ./lucee.run Then I got a message "No command 'run' found, did you mean:  followed by a list of about ten packages.  Can anyone enlighten me as to what to do?

Comment: well, I replaced the last instruction with sudo ./lucee.run and the installer went ahead, so I'm good

Answer (score 1):

To complement and for posterity, I'm adding this answer with new actual information. I've created a step by step video guide about installing Lucee on a clean Ubuntu Server 20.04.LTS and added them as a contribution to the official documentation. You can find the quick video guide at https://docs.lucee.org/guides/installing-lucee/installation-linux/linux-ubuntu-quick-video-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

so that summed up is:

Follow this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-railo-cfml-engine-with-tomcat-and-apache-on-a-debian-7-or-ubuntu-13-vps

replace with this:

> wget
>   http://lucee.viviotech.net/downloader.cfm/id/143/file/lucee-4.5.2.018-pl0-linux-x64-installer.run
>   -O lucee.run
>
> OR
>
> wget
>   http://d8yjolse1mixx.cloudfront.net/downloader.cfm/id/143/file/lucee-4.5.2.018-pl0-linux-x64-installer.run
>   -O lucee.run

based on the version here:

http://lucee.viviotech.net or http://lucee.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Drop the Jar or War install file into the correct folder for your J2EE engine.  Or use your engine's admin pages into install the that file.
Config changes can also be made to more fully integrate across instances.

Almost any engine will do: Jetty, Tomcat, GlassFish, JBoss and Elastic Beanstalk are all good choices.

Lucee is also now fully OSGi compliant.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started with Lucee is by using Ortus Solutions' [CommandBox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox). CommandBox comes with an embedded Lucee server so you can be up and running in just minutes. CommandBox is a standalone, native tool for Windows, Mac, and Linux that will provide you with a Command Line Interface (CLI), package management, embedded CFML server and application scaffolding.