# Need to print date in stdout logfile of tomcat

Tags: java

We have a web application, now we want to print date at `stdout` log file, actually we are printing the output using `System.out.println()` in so many java files. So, we want date & time in `stdout`/`stderr` logfiles at where we are getting the output(with out changing java files). 
please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to include the name of the function you're calling, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In the begin of programm you can override `println()` for your `System.out` and add `new Date()`

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
    @Override
    public void println(String s) {
       Date date = new Date();
       super.println(String.format("[%s] %s"), date, s);
    }
})
```

The same you can do with `System.setErr()`

If you allow to use **Java Instrumentation** then you can use Agent

```
package com.test.agent;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.util.Date;

public class AgentOutRewrite {

    public static void premain(String agentArgument, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        System.out.println("Agent VM replacement");

        System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out) {
            @Override
            public void println(String str) {
                super.println(new Date() + ": " + str);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: com.test.agent.AgentOutRewrite
```

If you create jar with this class for example Agent.jar
you can inject you agent into your program like that

`java -javaagent:Agent.jar YourProgram.jar`

For adding Agent to Tomcat you should change CATALINA_OPTS

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -javaagent:/path/to/YourAgentJar.jar"
```

just as in this post 
[Adding -javaagent to Tomcat 6 server, where do I put it and in what format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697063/adding-javaagent-to-tomcat-6-server-where-do-i-put-it-and-in-what-format)

Comment: we dont have a permission to change java files.

Comment: @SanthoshBhupathi I have added another approach without changing original code.